How do I debug in leetcode?
I am new to leetcode and extremely frustrated.  I wrote my first test program and I'm getting a runtime error.  I have the Debugger window open, but where it displays stdout it says, "Start the debugging session to check output here".  But there is no indication of how one starts a debugging session.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but my google searches have all turned up nothing.  Can someone help?

This is how it worked for me in my UI, and given a random problem.  Hopefully it will help you as well.  As you can see, first click to place breakpoint(s), then click the "debug" icon next to "Run" and "Submit", and finally play with the UI until it gives what you want.

Again, hope it helps, and obviously anyone who has a different UI may need to find the solution elsewhere.  Hope this helps!
EDIT: some further instructions for the following steps after, ie. how to step into, step over, etc. in the LeetCode debugger.
